# buying items while calculating it's price's constant math (javascript)

Tags: javascript, math, discord.js

Alright, first of all let me explain what I have...

I'm making a bot on discord using discord.js and it has a kinda different economy sys, that is not important at all.

On this sys, there is a command to buy items, but... the problem is, the item changes it's price based on the amount of times you already bought it. Here is the price formula:

`var ItemNamePreco = Math.pow(amountOfItems*27, 1.6)`

The idea is, whenever you send a buy command, it gets your gold amount, and if you have more than the Item's price, you'll buy it.

The current code I have to make it work considering the price constant is:

```
var gold = 10000000000000000000;   
var atkbasico = 10;
var AtkBasicoPreco = Math.pow(atkbasico*27, 1.6);

let buyQtd = 0;

    if(gold < AtkBasicoPreco){

        return console.log(`You don't have enough gold to buy AtkBasico`);

    } else {

        while(gold > AtkBasicoPreco){

            var AtkBasicoPreco = Math.pow(atkbasico*27, 1.6);
            

            atkbasico++;
            gold-AtkBasicoPreco;
            buyQtd++;   
        
        }

        return console.log(`You bought ${buyQtd} Atks Básicos. Now you have ${atkbasico}`);

    }
    
    // this is just an example where your node will take yeaaaaaaars to calculate the amount of items you can buy.
```

It works as I want, but, when the amount of items you can buy starts to get high (like 100+), the bot starts to lag and take a lot of time to calculate it. And I want it to calculate like the price of +1e29 items instantly.

I believe this is more related to math than to coding but still, any help is appreciated.